# Where is the created pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to use maven goal of `eclipse:to-maven`, contained in Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin (RETIRED).

When I executed `eclipse:to-maven` with `-DeclipseDir` option, it prints `BUILD SUCCESS` like the following, but I cannot find the created `pom.xml`.

```
C:\Users\sample\Desktop\sample>mvn eclipse:to-maven -DeclipseDir="../jee-oxygen/eclipse"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:to-maven (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Processing file C:\Users\sample\Desktop\jee-oxygen\eclipse\plugins\ch.qos.logback.classic_1.0.7.v20121108-1250.jar
...
skip the middle part
...
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sample\Desktop\jee-oxygen\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.datatools.help_1.7.0.201701131441.jar to C:\Users\sample\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\datatools\help\1.7.0-201701131441\help-1.7.0-201701131441.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.557 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-22T06:00:23+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/621M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using

- Windows 10 Pro
- Maven 3.5.0
- 1.8.0_131
- Eclipse Oxygen.1 Release (4.7.1)

And I tried it with other version, like maven 3.3.9 and eclipse Juno, but this did not solve my problem.

edited.

I thought `eclipse:to-maven` goal is for my eclipse project, so I expected the created `pom.xml` is for my eclipse project.
I know converting to maven project in eclipse UI, but I would like to know if there are plugins or goals that enable to convert eclipse projects to maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

From [eclipse:to-maven plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/to-maven-mojo.html)

> Add eclipse artifacts from an eclipse installation to the local repo. This mojo automatically analize the eclipse directory, copy plugins jars to the local maven repo, and generates appropriate poms.

So you should search in your local maven repo.

For example pom generated for `org.eclipse.datatools.help` should be installed at `C:\Users\hyojinbae\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\datatools\help\1.7.0-201701131441\help-1.7.0-201701131441.pom`

Comment: I found the pom.xml in my local repository and I realized my question is not good. I added more question. Thank you.